# Capturing return value from remote post hander

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a number of forms set up using Webforms (the module formerly known as yamlforms) in Drupal 8.

This data is stored in Drupal, but is also sent to a remote CRM using a Remote post handler added to the form. The CRM handler generates a key for the newly added lead that I would like to use in my success message. There's no option for capturing data from a remote post though.

Does a solution already exist for this, or am I doomed to writing my own module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in solution for this, you have extend the Remote post handler and write some custom code.

Please open a ticket in the [Webform issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/webform). Ideally, the remote post handler would be able to populate some meta data that could be exposed via a token.

Comment: I opened a ticket. I'm not holding my breath about support arriving in time for me. 

In a pinch I can just have my form submit to an external url.

Comment: @jrockowitz committed a solution for this https://www.drupal.org/node/2898424 included since 8.x-5.0-beta16